# How to create JSON object Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to create a JSON object in Node.js without any success.
For example an object like this:

```
{ 'Orientation Sensor': 
   [ { sampleTime: '1450632410296',
       data: '76.36731:3.4651554:0.5665419' },
     { sampleTime: '1450632410296',
       data: '78.15431:0.5247617:-0.20050584' } ],
  'Screen Orientation Sensor': 
   [ { sampleTime: '1450632410296',
       data: '255.0:-1.0:0.0' } ],
  'MPU6500 Gyroscope sensor UnCalibrated': 
   [ { sampleTime: '1450632410296',
       data: '-0.05006743:-0.013848438:-0.0063915867},
     { sampleTime: '1450632410296',
       data: '-0.051132694:-0.0127831735:-0.003325345'}]}
```

but in a dynamic way without any knowledge about the size of every item.
Is there something like that in Node.js?

Comment: Do you have any additional code you can show for how you're trying now?

Comment: There is no "JSON"-Object, what do you mean?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

What I believe you're looking for is a way to work with arrays as object values:

```
var o = {} // empty Object
var key = 'Orientation Sensor';
o[key] = []; // empty Array, which you can push() values into


var data = {
    sampleTime: '1450632410296',
    data: '76.36731:3.4651554:0.5665419'
};
var data2 = {
    sampleTime: '1450632410296',
    data: '78.15431:0.5247617:-0.20050584'
};
o[key].push(data);
o[key].push(data2);
```

This is standard JavaScript and not something NodeJS specific. In order to serialize it to a JSON string you can use the native `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify(o);
//> '{"Orientation Sensor":[{"sampleTime":"1450632410296","data":"76.36731:3.4651554:0.5665419"},{"sampleTime":"1450632410296","data":"78.15431:0.5247617:-0.20050584"}]}'
```

Comment: Just wanted to add since this answer still seems to get attention from time to time, an idiomatic one-liner for initializing non-existing keys in an object to an empty array is `o[key] = o[key] || []`, i.e. make it equal to itself or an empty array if it is falsey.

The `||` operator will return the last truthy value due to short-circuiting.

Answer (score 8):

The JavaScript `Object()` constructor makes an Object that you can assign members to.

```
myObj = new Object()
myObj.key = value;
myObj[key2] = value2;   // Alternative
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but it's not clear what the Question exactly is asking for

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are helpful, but the JSON in your question isn't valid. I have formatted it to make it clearer below, note the missing single quote on line 24.

```
  1 {
  2     'Orientation Sensor':
  3     [
  4         {
  5             sampleTime: '1450632410296',
  6             data: '76.36731:3.4651554:0.5665419'
  7         },
  8         {
  9             sampleTime: '1450632410296',
 10             data: '78.15431:0.5247617:-0.20050584'
 11         }
 12     ],
 13     'Screen Orientation Sensor':
 14     [
 15         {
 16             sampleTime: '1450632410296',
 17             data: '255.0:-1.0:0.0'
 18         }
 19     ],
 20     'MPU6500 Gyroscope sensor UnCalibrated':
 21     [
 22         {
 23             sampleTime: '1450632410296',
 24             data: '-0.05006743:-0.013848438:-0.0063915867
 25         },
 26         {
 27             sampleTime: '1450632410296',
 28             data: '-0.051132694:-0.0127831735:-0.003325345'
 29         }
 30     ]
 31 }
```

There are a lot of great articles on how to manipulate objects in Javascript (whether using Node JS or a browser). I suggest here is a good place to start:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: thank you, i am little new to Java Script. i will be helpful :]